# my mtk device with mt6572 (Karbonn a35) dual core and 512 mb ram crashes on gameplay

Tags: crashes

My phone crashes on some games but i have sufficient system requirement . Games such as eagle sim,robocop,shadow fight 2,exile far colony etc crashes frequently please friends gave any solution

Answer (score 1):

shadow fight 2 needs at lest 1GB ram for smooth running..you can play dead trigger 1 on your phone. it is working on 512 mb ram dual core phones..